# Blocked from saving post

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I recently took on a new client in NYC to speed up their website. 
The website was constantly getting grade speed F on pingdom and gtmetrix. I set to work adding the website to Stackpath CDN, disabling plugins, adding the website to Cloudflare and properly configuring W3TC on the website, something I have done on multiple client websites many times before!

As a result the the website now has a grade [B on Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/IelzY/https://www.urbannaturale.com/) and a grade [A on GTMETRIX](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.urbannaturale.com/EJodlxva). I also tested the website on [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.urbannaturale.com&s=104.18.58.197) to make sure everything is ok there. Nothing out of the ordinary there also!

That said my client has been having issues with the website getting a "Sorry, you have been blocked" when she tries to save a post. Also she cannot add images, insert links and multiple other things when editing a blog post! I made a test post and everything was fine there. But naturally I am not experiencing the problems my client is experiencing.

Here is a screenshot my client just sent me showing the problem...
[image: Blocked from editing] at one stage yesterday mu client got an UNSAFE WEBSITE warning on the SSL and sent me this screeny...

[image: Unsafe Website]

For me everything is fine and I think it may be something to do with Cloudflare but then again it could be WordFence on the website!
Grateful for any help in this or any clues!

Comment: Just to let everyone know I have tried to edit a post on behalf my client and Now I also am getting the Sorry, you have been blocked window for some reason!

Comment: Off topic: think of improving the quality of https://www.urbannaturale.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/new-logo.jpg It looks horrible when zooming in.

Comment: Hi Paul, the theme itself was not my job. I have only made steps to speed up the website! That said I am a WordPress Theme Developer and I create custom built ones for my clients. It all depends on if this client wants me to replace the current one or not. Thanks for your imput anyway!

Comment: They do seem to be using Cloudflare, where they can change settings and headers to help improve their security further, according to [securityheaders.io](https://securityheaders.io/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbannaturale.com%2F&followRedirects=on). I had a long delay while the site loaded, but according to [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/171029_K0_5e3376877a91c24ae9d62abcded8b739/) the site is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sounds like they need to adjust their [WAF](https://www.cloudflare.com/waf/) settings at Cloudflare to avoid the "Sorry, you have been blocked" message. According to [Cloudflare Support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203215830-Why-do-some-visitors-get-a-You-have-bee-blocked-error-message-):

> Cloudflare customers on a paid Cloudflare plan have access to a
>   feature called a Web Application Firewall (WAF). If a visitor is
>   getting that error message trying to access your site, that user is
>   triggering a rule in the Web Application Firewall instructing
>   Cloudflare to block that visitor. You can view and take action against
>   that event by going to the Traffic app in the Cloudflare dashboard,
>   where you can see which rule was specifically triggered by that
>   visitor.

Comment: Thank you Michael, that's really strange. I have followed what was suggested and there is nothing showing up there in the traffic app. What I find weird is that I am logged in as normal as admin and I should be able to update a post as normal but it thinks I am attacking it!
I have also tried disabling Wordfence as well but that made no difference